# if $A=B\cup C$, then $A$ is the pushout of $B\leftarrow B\cap C\rightarrow C$

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading the proof of Proposition 1.4.3 in [Johnstone, Sketches of an elephant, Part A].

It take the projection $\pi: C\times D\to D$ and says that $\exists_\pi:\text{Sub}(C\times D)\to \text{Sub}(D)$.
That's if $m$ is a subobject of $C\times D$ then $m\circ \pi$ is a subobject of $D$.
This is true if $\pi$ is a monomorphism, but in this case $\pi$ don't need to be a monomorphism. How to guarantee this?

Comment: Are $B, C$ sets or elements of an arbitrary category?

Comment: Yes, $\pi \circ m $ is rarely ever monic, but $\exists_\pi m$ is obtained
from the monic part in the epi-mono factorization of $\pi \circ m $.

Comment: You are right, $\exists_\pi(m)$ is the image of $m\circ\pi$.

Comment: @Ma Ming: $A,B,C$ are object of a coherent category.